# Is "Crack in the World" available on DVD/online?

Tags: crack-in-the-world-1965

I remember watching [this film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059065) years ago on Channel 4 as part of a sci-fi festival of film but can't find it anywhere on DVD. Has it ever been released,or is available to stream from any legit site?

Comment: Which one? Could you provide a link to the IMDB entry?

Comment: @Donald.McLean - why do you ask "which one"? IMDB shows there was only ever one film with that name: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059065

Comment: Right. My mistake - the others are TV episodes.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably specify what country you're from--from the fact that you refer to a channel by number alone, I'd guess the UK? It doesn't seem to have been released there, but if you get a multiregion DVD or blu ray player you could get the U.S. release, it's on amazon [here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Crack-World-DVD-Region-NTSC/dp/B003J216K4).

edit: I see there is also an Italian release that's region 2 like the UK, so you could get that if you don't have/don't want to buy a multiregion player, it's available from amazon [here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Esperimento-I-S-Il-Mondo-Frantuma/dp/B0055STN64/).

Answer (score 1):

You can watch the full movie [here](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xls663_crack-in-the-world_shortfilms). 
The quality is a bit poor but it's certainly watchable.

If you want to part with money, you can buy a DVD or Bluray copy on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Crack-World-Blu-ray-US-Import/dp/B004VDSWGG)

Comment: No illegal item promotion please.

Comment: @SachinShekhar - It seems very unlikely that the current rights-holder will object to a low quality link to a low budget film that's over 50 years old, right next to a link where you can buy a legal copy.